# Resource overriding

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

I'm building an Android app. It's compound by two modules. The specific module and the core module. In the core module I've defined basic app components, styles and activities. In the specific one, I make the customizations for each customer.

My problem is that I have an attribute defined in `core > styles.xml > AppTheme > myAttr` and I want to override it in `specific > styles.xml > MyAppTheme (which extends from AppTheme) > myAtrr`. Result is that if I use `?attr/myAttr` in XML layout the value is always the one from the core part, it's not being overriden by the specific part value.

If I try to use the attribute in code using `getActivity().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes()` the result is the one from the core part.

Any thought on what is going on here is wellcome, thanks.

**Code structure**

I've defined in core styles.xml a default resource in a theme called `AppTheme`:

```xml
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="cat_commstate_loading_transition">@drawable/commstate_loading</item>
    </style>

    <attr name="cat_commstate_loading_transition" format="reference"/>
</resources>
```

and the `commstate_loading.xml` is defined as:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false"
    android:visible="true">

    <item
        android:duration="225"
        android:drawable="@mipmap/commstate_loading_1"/>

    <item
        android:duration="225"
        android:drawable="@mipmap/commstate_loading_2"/>

    <item
        android:duration="225"
        android:drawable="@mipmap/commstate_loading_3"/>

</animation-list>
```

and I use the resource like this:

```xml
 <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
            android:id="@+id/act_challenge_transition_loading_animation"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="?attr/cat_commstate_loading_transition" />
```

So, I have a default animation which is working fine in several projects.

Now, in the situation I want to override a resource, I would extend the `AppTheme` defined in the core part in the specific one like this:

```xml
<resources>
    <style name="MyAppTheme" parent="@style/AppTheme">
        <item name="cat_commstate_loading_transition">@drawable/commstate_loading_corporate</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And the `commstate_loading_corporate` resource is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false"
    android:visible="true">

    <item
        android:duration="225"
        android:drawable="@mipmap/commstate_loading_corporate_1"/>

    <item
        android:duration="115"
        android:drawable="@mipmap/commstate_loading_corporate_2"/>

    <item
        android:duration="115"
        android:drawable="@mipmap/commstate_loading_corporate_3"/>

    <item
        android:duration="115"
        android:drawable="@mipmap/commstate_loading_corporate_4"/>

    <item
        android:duration="115"
        android:drawable="@mipmap/commstate_loading_corporate_5"/>

</animation-list>
```

From my point of view, at this point, the reference `?attr/cat_commstate_loading_transition` should make reference to the `commstate_loading_corporate` resource, since I override it.

Comment: Is that xml's activity using `MyAppTheme` in manifest.

Comment: @VivekMishra updated question to show the manifest definition

Comment: can you share your style

Comment: Also core code portions

Comment: @ManojPerumarath updated question

Comment: Couldn't you override the attr tag too in the specific styles.xml?

Comment: @GiorgioBertolotti Do you mean placing `<attr name="cat_commstate_loading_transition" format="reference"/>` on the specific styles.xml ? That's not possible since I receive this error: `Error: Found item Attr/cat_commstate_loading_transition more than one time`

Answer (score 0):

I propose you to use [product flavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#product-flavors). With help of product flavors you can define [source sets](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#sourcesets) and override any part of core module (resources, assets, java sources).

Comment: Thanks, that seems an interesting alternative, but due to the project size and structure I 'd rather something similar to the proposal on my question.